# Inequality with summations

Tags: calculus, statistics, inequality

Let $x=(x_1,...x_n) ,x_i>0 \,\,\forall i$ , then

$(\sum_ix_i^3)/(\sum_ix_i^2)^2\geq 1/(\sum_ix_i)$

Any suggestions on how to prove this?
thanks

Comment: Hint: Cauchy Schwartz inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired inequality is equivalent to $(\sum_i x_i^3)(\sum_i x_i) \geq (\sum_i x_i^2)^2$, which follows directly from the Cauchy-Schwartz [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality) with $u_i=\sqrt{x_i}$ and $v_i=x_i^{\frac{3}{2}}$.